# С помощью каких технологий создают простые сайты?

Tags: веб-программирование, frontend, backend, веб-сайт

С помощью каких технологий создают сейчас простые сайты?
Понятно что html,css,js, с помощью чего делают простой бекенд? Формы например. Или где хранят какие-то категории товаров и тд. Погуглив немного у меня сложилось чувство что кроме PHP по факту ничего толком нельзя применить. Поделитесь, пожалуйста, всем стеком технологий (фронт, бек, препроцессоры и тд) которые вы используете, только без CMS. Спасибо!

Comment: В бэк можно и NodeJS и Python. PHP не один и его выбирать я бы не советовал. Если вы хотите выбрать что-то готовое и не трогать более, то и PHP движки подойдут. Но если вы интересуетесь с целью дальнейшей разработки - не пробуйте даже PHP.

Comment: дело просто в том, что хостить тот же nodejs где-то нужно. Я не люблю php и оно мне не нравится и учить его тоже не особо хочу)) просто даже на том же фронте нужен какай-то шаблонизатор, но то такое, а вот хостинги все по умолчанию поддерживают php и mysql

Comment: Я не совсем понял вашего комментария. Вы боитесь установить на впс нод приложение? А для пхп по-сути ничего делать не нужно и в этом плюс? Не проще научиться ставить на впс, чем копаться в мусоре (пхп) ?

Answer (score 3):

Быстро создать простой сайт можно на Python. Это точно, про остальные языки говорить не берусь.

**Frontend**:

- Можно заюзать бесплатный адаптивный Bootstrap-шаблон с [html5up](https://html5up.net/)
- Можно купить готовый адаптивный Bootstrap-шаблон в [магазине Bootstrap](https://themes.getbootstrap.com)
- Никто не запрещает написать фронт самому или отдать на фриланс. Отмечу, что сегодня верстка стоит дорого, это особое ремесло, которое требует уйму усилий
- AJAX и JavaScript'ы для общения с Backend'ом за вами

**Backend**:

- Python/Django - комбайн в котором из коробки есть все, что может понадобиться
- Python/Flask - Только самый необходимый минимум для работы сайта, но благодаря модулям его легко можно "прокачать" до функционала Django
- GoLang - Подарит скорость в разработке и скорость в обслуживании запросов

Отдельно отмечу плюсы Python в этом вопросе:

- Быстрое прототипирование
- Код относительно легко можно ускорить откомпилировав с помощью Cython
- Python можно использовать чем-то вроде "Клея", как говорил Bobuk. Вы можете переписать проблемный код на Go или Cython и вызывать этот код из Python

**DataBase**

Если сайт действительно простой, возможно DB вам и не понадобиться

- SQLite - крайний минимум. Его можно использовать только для совсем маленьких/домашних проектов, не предполагающих развития и/или высокой нагрузки. Не поддается масштабированию, так как в нем нет репликации данных
- MySql - Ничего не могу сказать о данной БД. Не должна Вас подвести. Бесплатна
- MsSql - Хорошо, но дорого. Только для Windows
- PostrgreSQL - Очень хорошо и бесплатно. Вход легкий, но по мере роста проекта с документацией иметь дело придется, благо там лучшая документация из всех что я когда либо видел. Есть репликация, ваш сайт можно будет масштабировать для высоких нагрузок

Специализированные СУБД, которые могут пригодиться для оптимизации, но не стоит начинать с них:

- MongoDB - Документоориентированная БД. Может быть очень удобна в использовании, неприхотлива при изменении структуры данных. Оочень быстрая. Может пригодиться при оптимизации сайта, если часть оперативных данных вы перенесете из основной БД в нее. (Я в ней не спец) может случиться такое, что функционал классической, реляционной БД, вам очень понадобиться, но его не будет, если вы выберете MongoDB. Реляционная модель хорошо себя зарекомендовала за те десятилетия, которыми мы ими пользуемся, NoSQL - еще нов. Кстати, в 12й версии PostgreSQL появились функции, реализующие NoSQL-функционал
- ClickHouse - Сверхбыстрая БД для очень узкоспециализированных задач. Главный плюс - быстрая выборка на большом отрезке данных. Может пригодиться для аналитических запросов

Сервер:

- WSGI - встроенный веб-сервер Flask. Только для отладки и только дома
- Apache - только дома
- NGINX - Тут без альтернатив. Быстр, надежен и настраивается даже легче Apache. Не рекомендуется для использования в Windows из-за особенности выделения памяти Windows. Особенно хорош под FreeBSD

Хостить можно, например, на VPS от DigitalOcean. Тут конечно свои нюансы, но в целом, думаю что вам понравиться. Устанавливаете Linux и не знаете бед: обновления ОС, Python, PostgreSQL, Nginx, все что угодно и на одной машине за 230р/мес. Легко отмастабируетесь как вертикально, так и горизонтально. Если что, переедете (не реклама)

> P.S. Вы ступаете на довольно опасную территорию. Думайте о
>   безопасности. Не только о хакерах, но и о юристах. Возможно ваш сайт
>   должен иметь пользовательское соглашение, согласие на обработку
>   персональных данных - это документы на сайт. 
>   Если вы собираете личные данные пользователей - вы обязаны эти данные защищать всеми доступными методами. Ознакомьтесь с OWASP, LetsEncrypt, шифрованием с солью, библиотекой hashlib, если пишете на Python

Answer (score 2):

> с помощью чего делают простой бекенд?

Существует множество различных подходов и технологий, почитайте подробне про REST, MVC, SSR, но если я правильно понял ваш вопрос и вы хотите узнать технологии и языки, с которыми чаще создают именно 'простой бекенд', то это скорее JavaScript/TypeScript(Node.JS) и Python(Django, Flask), для более масштабных/корпоративных приложений - это скорее Java/C#/Go и тд. Но выбор языка и платформы всегда зависит от цели и конкретной ситуации.

> Или где хранят какие-то категории товаров и тд

Данные хранятся в базе данных, тут тоже выбор большой и все зависит от задачи (PostgreSQL, MySQL,MsSQl на пример)

> Погуглив немного у меня сложилось чувство что кроме PHP по факту ничего толком нельзя применить.

Это совсем не так, как я уже написал выше, выбор довольно большой и у каждого свои плюсы и минусы.

А вообще, если вы вы выбираете какой стек изучать, сначала лучше определиться что вам ближе, frontend/backend/fullstack, и исходя из этого уже подбирать технологии

Comment: я отталкиваюсь так же от хостинга для таких простых сайтов, то есть стоимость таких хостингов дешевая. Если же я буду создавать бекенд на nodejs или еще круче c#, то мне нужны специальные платформы для этого, типа heroku для nodejs. То есть проблема в хосте всего этого. Та же проблема с и бд.

Comment: Это зависит от поставщика хостинга и услуг, которые он предоставляет, не могу сказать текущую ситуацию по другим, но reg.ru сейчас дает поддержку PHP, Python и Perl. И MySQL базу данных. Так что вполне можно писать на Python.

Answer (score 0):

Формы это html, а бекенд - может быть почти все что угодно, что может работать с протоколами передачи данных, и базами данных.